# Can git repository not include unix named fifo?

Tags: git, named-pipes, mkfifo

I think I know the answer to this, from experimentation, but my googling has found nothing definitive about it. So I'm looking for clarification. Consider

```
cd GitDirectory
mkfifo _my_named_pipe
git add _my_named_pipe
git status
```

The `status` command will show nothing. My *conclusion* is that you can't put named pipes in a git repository. Have I reached the correct conclusion? Or is there something I missed here?

Comment: What would be the point at all? I don't see any use for a named pipe inside a git repository. If a program needs one, it can create it if one does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, git only handles regular files and symbolic links (well, also trees and submodules, but they get handled specially internally).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, is there a specific reference for this, that I could not find? I assume it's more than oral tradition and trial-and-error.

Comment: I don't know of any specific documentation that forbids named pipes, but it's in the source, e.g., in `read-cache,c` the only permitted mode values are "regular file", "link", and "gitlink".  See `add_to_index`.